# Validating Regex match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to verify the `ID` and what I'm doing wrong?

below is my code:

```
ID: "a485c610-7d49-4877-a4c9-bdaaaad417be"

public ActionResult Verify(string id)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id) || (!Regex.IsMatch(id, @"[0-9a-f]{8}\-([0-9a-f]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}")))
   {
       //oops
   }
   else {
       //good
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use Guid.TryParse()

Comment: What should a valid ID look like - what do you expect the outcome to be. What makes you say this is "wrong"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor your regex, and there is no need to escape `-` outside a character class:

```
@"^[0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}$"
```

`^` and `$` matches the beginning and the end of the string respectively.

Answer (score 3):

As Jonesy said, why not use `Guid.TryParse()`

```
string stringGuid = "a485c610-7d49-4877-a4c9-bdaaaad417be";
Guid newGuid;

if (Guid.TryParse(stringGuid, out newGuid))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to a Guid", stringGuid);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert {0} to a Guid", stringGuid);
```

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) for more info